# bootstrap navbar + jquery + traversing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am close enough with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3X7/9/) but would appreciate some advise.

How do I make this work so that if I select TopMenu it is highlighted 
Then If I select TopMenu -> Hour -> SubMenu1 all 3 would be highlighted and all others would be de-highlighted.

I feel I am close with this code:

```
$(".dropdown-submenu li").click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    //$(this).parent.addClass("active");
    $(this).prev(".dropdown-submenu").addClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Currently it works that TopMenu -> Hour -> SubMenu1, only SubMenu1 will be highlighted. whereas I want all 3 to be highlighted (i.e. (1)TopMenu (2)Hour (3)SubMenu1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).parent().find('ul').length) {
        // no children
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parents('li').addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: tks that pretty much works [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3X7/10/) but how do i get TopMenu22->Overview/Hour to work similarilty in this examaple. Its a slightly different structure

Comment: For now I could just keep all the dropdown menus uniformly the same 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3X7/11/)
that way  Iwould have TopMenu22 -> Overview -> Overview and all 3 will be highlighted. Even though there is duplication with Overview here TWICE

Comment: ahhh...if i select TopMenu->Hour then these 2 will be highlighted but I don't want them highlighted but I do want TopMenu22->Overview/Hour (all 2) to be highlighted, will have to look at this again...

Comment: I'll leave the jsfiddle collaboration feature open for the next couple hours, if I see you on maybe we can work through it. The jsfiddle collaboration link is at: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3X7/12/#&togetherjs=v1PmQiHmOy).

Comment: just joined that link if its not too late?

Comment: I jumped on again, not sure if i saw you on or not.  I'll leave it open for a bit longer.

Comment: Updated answer based on your comments in the jsfiddle